# Exceptions when changing visibility on stackpanel

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0

I have two stack panel, containing each, one datagrid.

I set the itemsSource of my datagrid when the source are loaded.

My panels are collapsed in the beginning, and then, must appears when I checked one RadioButton.

Here is the xaml of stackpanel :

```
                            <StackPanel Name="spListeList"
                                        Grid.Row="0"
                                        Grid.Column="2"
                                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                                        Visibility="Collapsed">
                                <sdk:DataGrid Name="dgListList" 
                                              VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                              AutoGenerateColumns="False"   
                                              AlternatingRowBackground="Orange" 
                                              IsReadOnly="True">
                                    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                                        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding IdList, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                                        Visibility="Collapsed"
                                                        Width="10"/>
                                        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header=" "
                                                        Width="85"
                                                        Binding="{Binding LibList, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                                </sdk:DataGrid>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Name="spListeJury"
                                        Grid.Row="0"
                                        Grid.Column="3"
                                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                                        Visibility="Collapsed">
                                <sdk:DataGrid Name="dgListeJury" 
                                              VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                              AutoGenerateColumns="False"   
                                              AlternatingRowBackground="Orange" 
                                              IsReadOnly="True">
                                    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                                        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding IdJury, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                                        Visibility="Collapsed"
                                                        Width="10"/>
                                        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header=" "
                                                        Width="85"
                                                        Binding="{Binding LibJury, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                                    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                                </sdk:DataGrid>

                            </StackPanel>
```

I got 10 radioButton, and 2 handler(similar except for names) for them.

```
void rbListeList_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (templateColumnListeList == null)
        {
            templateColumnListeList = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
        }

        dgListeList.Columns.Remove(templateColumnListeList);
        templateColumnListeList.Header = "Select";
    templateColumnListeList.CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["ItemTemplateSelect"];
    dgListeList.Columns.Add(templateColumnListeList);
    templateColumnListeList.DisplayIndex = 0;
    spListeList.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    spListeJury.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception(ex.Message);
}
```

}

When I comment the lines changing the visibility, nothing goes wrong. But when it's not, I got a ArgumentOutOfBound Exception

And when the two panels are visible on the beginning, they appears well, without bug. And the template colums appears too when I click on a radioButton and goes into the handler...

I tried another one : 
when i star with both visible, application running well, and panels appears and desappears the way I want... So it's seems, there is a problem when I star with both collapsed.

Can't I change visibility on panels, containing Source when application is running?

Thank you.

Comment: If you step into the code, where does the ArgumentOutOfBound exception gets thrown?

Comment: In the end of the try block.

Comment: It gets thrown on each visibility change? I kinda suspect it comes from `templateColumnListeList.DisplayIndex = 0;`

Comment: Me too. But, when I stat with both visible, applicatiopn running well... Even the visibility changes...

Comment: Have you tried commenting only one of the 2 visibility lines? Let's see if only one of them throw the exception.

Comment: Well, it seems that it's the Visibility.Visible bugging. But why only when I start with collapsed?

Answer (score 0):

When you set the Visibility="Collapsed" in XAML, that control is not Instantiated when the Window Loads. Try Visibility="Hidden" if using WPF. Silverlight Doesn't support Hidden visibility. or try setting the Collapsed property in Loaded event of the Window.

Comment: Ok, I set visibility after  setting the items source. Well, there is no more exception, but datagrid never appears...

Comment: Why you placed DataGrid Inside a stack panel?  Stack Panel stacks items Horizontally/Vertically based on Orientation Property. Try using Grid for DataGrid.

Comment: DataGrid does not show means that the ItemsSource you setting to the property is null.

Answer (score 0):

I would say there is an issue with the  column code above but it is hard to tell without more code. I normally bind the visibility property of the control to a property on the datacontext for the page and set that value when needed. If you post a little more code I could be of more help.